# How to use in-video ads?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm not sure how to use the in-video ads.
I use JWplayer and . Here is what the Ad network provides.

With the embed tag :

```
...
wmode="transparent"
...
```

If you use JWPlayer (JS library or object HTML tag) as a player and SWFobject 2.2 for other flash animations in your pages, add the following parameter:

```
var params = {
...
ignore_swfobject: '1'
...
};
```

And the Ad code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var exoOpts = {
  cat: '118',
  login: 'thelogin',
  idzone_300x250: '720635',
  idzone_468x60: '720635',
  idsite: '243347',
  pause: {},
  postroll: {},
  show_thumb: '1'
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ads.exoclick.com/invideo.js"></script>
```

I'm really new at this and I don't know where to put everything.
Can you please explain and make it really easy?
I use Wordpress as a CMS.
Thanks